# Copper Ptrap snapped during bathroom demo, how to fix?

Tags: plumbing, pipe, copper

Trying to demo my bathroom for a remodel, had the P-trap snap because it was corroded. I'm left with what's below. What items do I need to repair this? I imagine I would want some PVC to Copper connector and get a PVC P-trap? But there are so many available: https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_2?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=P-trap I have no clue what to choose.

Also there is a bolt behind that cover in the picture, but it won't budge a centimeter. I assume I would need to remove that part that is broken, but what/how do I replace it? And what should I use to unscrew it since it won't budge a tiny bit trying with pliers.

[image]

Better pic behind the cover: [image]

My weak attempt at measuring: [image]

Comment: Have you tried some wd40 to loosen the rust hold on the screw? You need to remove that cover first. See how much spare pipe you have, then determine the course of action. Howevee, a pic or plastic ptrap is what you need. Find the correct size as the pipe you have now. The ptrap setup should have everything you need to connect the two materials together. Usually a plastic nut with a compression ring washer. You'll slide the new system into the old pipe and secure it with the but and ring, compressing the ring into the void.

Comment: Behind that flanged piece (bell shaped) should be a Desanco fitting which is an adapter piece that allows you to connect a p or s trap to that drain piping. As mentioned it has a nut and a compression ring.If this is the case, you can turn the nut ccw.and remove the broken piece, slide out the old piece and install a new trap. If the broken piece is soldered into the "T" behind it, then you will have to un-solder that broken piece to remove it and solder i9n a new Desanco fitting

Comment: @JeffCates I've added 2 extra pictures, can you link me a product that handles the connector, also I'm not sure (embarassingly) how to accurately measure a pipe. Did I measure it in the right spot? Or should it be behind the joint?

Comment: @d.george I've edited with extra pictures,  Is it soldered? I can't tell due to my newbieness. And how to you unsolder it? I've got a basic solder kit.

Comment: It is not soldered. Put a wrench on the large nut, that is just behind that flange piece, with the wrench handle pointing to your left. Push the wrench down to loosen the nut. Turn the nut all the way off, then you should be able to remove the broken piece of pipe by turning the pipe back and forth. Take the broken piece to a hardware store or a home builder supply and they can give you the replacement parts. If this is a bathroom sink it will be an 1-1/4" trap assembly

Comment: I was referencing the 2nd picture, the one with the feet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Soak it good with penetrating oil. Then use a pipe wrench if you have one. Righty tighty, lefty loosy. Yes your measurement will work. Most kitchens are 1 1/4" and bathrooms are 1 1/2" however this can be different. Looks like you have 1 1/2". Get a new kit similar to this http://www.homedepot.com/p/Everbilt-1-1-2-in-Plastic-P-Trap-C9704B/205153793 plus any adapters you need that are not in the kit. Some kits have everything you need and more, some only a few necessary parts.

Answer (score 0):

What type of pliers are you using? If you're using regular pliers either of these two options should give your more leverage.

[Channel Lock Pliers](https://www.channellock.com/420-straight-jaw-plier.aspx?) Picture is for reference, many different brands are availabel

Another option is a [pipe wrench](https://www.zoro.com/ridgid-pipe-wrench-6-l-cast-iron-31000/i/G1244074/?gclid=CjwKEAjw3pTJBRChgZ3e7s_YhAkSJAASG9VrXkUkxTJCkqSw7QnRbp4yjPjpKaTkzFL1En4C08pzQRoCcv7w_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds)

Soak it with some penetrating oil and let it sit overnight and try again.

Comment: I'm using the thing like the tongue jaw one in your first link.